# Using intermediate variables inside a Spark map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection

Does creating intermediate variables inside a `map` or a `flatMap` in Spark result in worse performance?

Here are two versions of some code that are supposed to do the same thing.

v1:

```
val x = someRDD.flatMap { case(id, row) => 
    if (row.flag.isDefined)
        Some((id, (Some(row.a.get), Some(row.b.get),
              if (someFunction(row.c.get) 1 else 0, 1)))
    else
        Some((id, (Some(row.a.get), None,
              if (someFunction(row.c.get) 1 else 0, 1)))
}
```

v2:

```
val x = someRdd.flatMap { case(id, row) =>
    val a = Some(row.a.get)
    val b = if (row.flag.isDefined) Some(row.b.get) else None
    val c = if (someFunction(row.c.get) 1 else 0
    Some((id, (a, b, c, 1)))
}
```

The difference is that v1 avoids creating any intermediate variables like v2 does.

Does v2 have worse performance compared to v1? Does the creation of the `a, b, c` vals require a later garbage collection step (eg: due to the cleanup [needed on the root objects](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/)) that makes it much slower?

Obviously, this is data dependent and detailed profiling is necessary to definitively answer the question but I wanted to know if, in general, using intermediate variables leads to worse performance.

I feel that from a code readability aspect, v2 is much better but if we defer to v1 would it be premature optimization?

Answer (score 3):

There probably will be no difference at all for primitive values (like your `c` variable). The compiler is smart enough to optimize it. For reference types creating a value formally does result in more garbage to collect, so theoretically yes, this might affect performance. However, in practice most likely you won't be able to notice a performance difference (unless you do create *a lot* of temporary objects, e.g hundreds and thousands of large arrays) - there are JIT optimizations which might kick in here, and also garbage collection is quite efficient these days, especially when handling lots of short-lived objects.

The best answer would be to profile your job, and do not attempt improving things like this in advance. I personally would look at optimizations like this as the very last step, after everything else stops to help. In the majority of cases, you can achieve much more impressive performance improvements by optimizing the plan of your job, e.g. by removing unnecessary shuffles or ensuring that your partitions have even size.